# Matching n or more defined consecutive character, excluding spaces

Tags: java, regex

I would like to match any extra `x` consecutive chars, excluding spaces, with a limit of 5 `x`:

1. `xxxxx` -> ∅
2. `xxxxxxxx` -> `xxx`
3. `x x x x x` -> ∅
4. `x x x x x x x x` -> `x x x`
5. `x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x` -> `x   x   x`

So basically, this regex works only for 1. and 2. :

```
^([x]{0,5})([x ]*)
```

How to allow spaces, without counting them?

Edit: The goal is to remove extra `x`, using Java.

Comment: Your regex and requirements are not clear, but perhaps, you are looking for `^((?:\s*x){0,5})([> ]*)`

Comment: What language are you using?  There might be an easier way just using vanilla string manipulation.

Comment: The goal is to remove extra `x`, using Java (I edited the question).

Comment: In #2 why are there only 3 `x`s? The `∅`s mean don't do anything because they already have 5?

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, you solution works! (note it was `x` in the second group, not `>`, I edited my regex). Could you post it as an answer and briefly explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a whitespace pattern into a non-capturing group and apply the limiting quantifier to this group instead on the `x` only:

```
^((?:\s*x){0,5})([x ]*)
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cYUzvz/1)

When you apply a quantifier (here, `{0,5}`) on a *group* the whole *sequence* is "repeated", and since only one `x` is inside the group (at its end), only 0 to 5 `x` can be matched with it, and any number of whitespaces.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `((?:\s*x){0,5})` - Group 1 capturing 0 to 5 sequences of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `x` - a literal `x`
- `([x ]*)`  - Group 2 capturing 0+ `x` or spaces.